# 2008 Honda CRV can't change ventilation mode

Tags: honda, ac, heater, crv

Heater works great and A/C works great when I turn the hot or cold knob.  Once I change blow mode to window defrost it stays there for several days even if I change the settings to other blow mode such as feet or face.  I know it has to do with one of the actuator but can someone help me pin point the actual name so I can order one.  There is heater blend actuator, air flap actuator, air duct actuator, and air door actuator.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!